# Finitely additive measures on Fréchet spaces

Tags: measure-theory, topological-vector-spaces

We are given a real Fréchet space $\mathfrak X$. Let $\mathcal B(\mathfrak X)$ denote its Borel sigma algebra and $\mathfrak X'$ its topological dual. Consider the following set-function:
$$
\mu: \mathcal B(\mathfrak X) \to \mathbb R
$$
such that

i) $\mu(\emptyset)=0$,

ii) finitely additive,

iii) finite and regular,

i.e. $\mu$ is an element of $rba(\mathfrak X)$, if we use the classical notation.

Suppose that the following equation holds true
$$
\mu[x\in\mathfrak X: \ell(x) < t]=0
$$
for any $\ell\in\mathfrak X'$ and $-\infty < t < \infty$.

Can one conclude that $\mu=0$?